# How to determine a floor function is inverse or not?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, special-functions

from Z to Z:
f(n)=2*floor(n/2)
How to determine if this function one-to-one and onto? In other words, how to determine a floor function is inverse or not?

Comment: Either solve for $n$ uniquely for all $y=f(n)$ or else find two values of $n$; say $n_1$ and $n_2$ such that $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$... what happens when $n_1=2k$ and $n_2=2k-1$?

Comment: To get a feeling for the function, compute a few values, say $f(0), f(1), f(2), f(3), f(4)$. This should show you immediately the answer to one part of the question and strongly suggest an idea for the other part.

Comment: You mean to say "invertible" (an adjective) rather than "inverse" (a noun). In general _being_ invertible means _having_ an inverse, which in the case of maps means being bijective (one-to-one and onto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- So your $f(n) = 2 \cdot \lfloor{\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}$. If $f$ was one one then different elements will have different images. But $f(2) = 2$ and $f(3)=2$. But $2 \neq 3$. So $2$ and $3$ go to the same elements and hence $f$ can't be $1-1$.
- To check $f$ that $f$ **isn't onto** take an element say $7 \in\mathbb{Z}$. You want to find a $y \in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $f(y) = 2 \cdot\lfloor{\frac{y}{2}\rfloor}=7$. This says $\lfloor{\frac{y}{2}\rfloor} =\frac{7}{2}$ which can't happen since $\lfloor{\frac{y}{2}\rfloor}$ is always an integer where as $\frac{7}{2}$ is a rational.

Comment: how about onto?

Comment: @Fan Kindly check. I have edited my answer.